# Is there a way for me to retrieve the questions asked by a deleted sockpuppet account of mine?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, accounts

I used my first Stack Overflow account for quite some time, but question-asking was disabled on that account because one particular question of mine was downvoted to oblivion.

There were some questions on that account that I still refer to every once in a while, and I ended up using that account as a sockpuppet to upvote questions on my current account so they would get more attention. Looking back, I'm not questioning that it was wrong to do that, but my account was suspended and the sockpuppet deleted. Is there a way to get the questions I asked on that account back?

Comment: I located those questions. There are quite a large number of poorly performing questions besides the one you mentioned, and the majority of them are deleted so you can't view them normally using your current account. But here are the ones that aren't deleted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49890818/css-transition-for-border-is-pushing-the-button-down https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49824510/how-do-i-make-a-fluid-checkerboard-background-that-contains-elements-inside-a-sq https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49808910/how-do-setters-work-in-javascript

Comment: @xdtTransform your comment doesn't really make sense grammatically, could you explain what it is you're trying to say?

Comment: Moderators already knew about him, that's why we removed the sockpuppet account. I'm not sure what your point is, @xdtTransform. We appreciate Jodast owning up to his mistakes, and the request that he made here is completely reasonable.

Comment: This is just some mental picture. -"Police removed your driving license and you decide to get a fake Id in order to get a new license."
and -"Using a fake account on FB to give you possitive reinforcement comment on every picture.". 
There is no real point, sockpuppet is not Id/License forgery. But somehow the approach is the same. 
I'm commenting the source of the issue.

Comment: The second comment was nothing more that a simple question: "You failed once. Do you want a quick review of your question?"
You "appreciate Jodast owning up to his mistakes". I only offer my simple understanding of the rules in order to prevent any issue.

Comment: After a quick unbiased review of the last 20 question. 
Open All 20 questions. Foreach question open random related question.
Till I get about 80+tabs, use a Css script to hide author of the question.
Close tab when the question is poor/bad. Unmask author, count number of quest where op is the author. 18/20.
The quality did improved since the question ban. Well done.

Comment: @xdtTransform yeah, but SO allows multiple accounts...

Comment: @Jodast, yes because one can have a Professional account, a student account, and evil twin account. Voting for each other is using an other Id to get priviledge and visibility.

Comment: @xdtTransform also I want to get it out of the way that I wasn't using the sockpuppet for evil, gaming the system.  I was using it to get more clicks on my question, and thus more answers

Comment: Good intentions. Does it matter? I'm not accusing you of beeing an evil man or anything. You have nothing to clear, puppet were destroy mod did thier job. We have nothing to win, talking about the past trying to justify ourself.

Comment: I have no idea what xdtTransform is saying in the comments here, but I just want to clarify that, while Stack Overflow allows you to have multiple accounts, those accounts are not allowed to *interact* with each other in any way. For the details, see [this canonical FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57685/153008). Note that this is not an accusation against anyone. Just a preemptive attempt to clarify.

Comment: @CodyGray thank you, I was wondering if that was a thing back when I made this account.

Comment: @Jodast: it always has been a thing. That FAQ post was written in 2010, your accounts where created last year.

Comment: @CodyGray I don't know if you were the one that found out about my sockpuppet, but how was it found out about?  Was it detected by an algorithm or did one of the mods notice it?

Comment: @MartijnPieters yeah, I just couldn't find it.  I didn't know what I was doing was called sockpuppeting at the time

Comment: Coincidentally, [I just answered a question about finding sockpuppets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381860/how-does-stack-overflow-detect-a-user-with-multiple-accounts-and-voting-each-oth/381862#381862).

Comment: I saw that, it's why I came back to comment.

Comment: Ah, well then... you should know that I cannot tell you any more information. :-) I can tell you it wasn't me who was involved, but I'm not sure that's particularly interesting.

Comment: Okay then, just curious.  I saw OP say that it was sometimes obvious when people sockpuppet and I was wondering if mine was done in a way that was obvious.  I guess it was probably the algo that found it tho, bc I did it a lot in one day.

Comment: @CodyGray is there a way for you to get the questions that account asked on Graphic Design Stack Exchange?  I need some of those questions atm

Comment: @Jodast You would have to ask a Graphic Design moderator for that. Post a question on their Meta.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no way for you to *regain ownership* of those questions. In other words, there's no way to reassociate them with your current account.

However, a moderator can give you links to all of the questions posted by your deleted sockpuppet account:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50009804/how-do-i-make-it-so-the-cancel-option-on-an-alert-does-not-appear
- [CSS transition for border is pushing the button down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49890818/css-transition-for-border-is-pushing-the-button-down)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49889311/how-do-i-make-an-active-link-affect-the-source-of-an-image-in-html-css-js
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49847321/color-is-applied-to-h1-tag-from-boostrap-but-the-color-is-nowhere-to-be-found-i
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49835885/how-do-i-make-the-color-scheme-change-when-the-page-is-reloaded
- [How do I make a fluid checkerboard background that contains elements inside a square in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49824510/how-do-i-make-a-fluid-checkerboard-background-that-contains-elements-inside-a-sq)
- [How do setters work in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49808910/how-do-setters-work-in-javascript)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49803410/what-is-the-easiest-language-to-learn-for-beginning-back-end-development
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49787647/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-div-that-appears-when-a-button-is-pressed-without-using
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49760517/how-do-i-put-certain-files-in-a-folder-in-github-without-using-git

Note that many of these questions are deleted (mostly by [the automatic cleanup process for "dead" questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions)), so you will not be able to see them without 10k+ reputation. You aren't missing anything.

Comment: I went through the deleted questions, and there's a jewel among them. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49787647 should probably be undeleted.

Comment: Where are you seeing the luster, @Joshua? Perhaps you can submit an edit that brings out the shine? That looks to me like a run-of-the-mill underspecified “write some code for me” question; in other words, “too broad”.

Comment: It would look me overtyping; but CSS only buttons are awesome.

Comment: @Joshua I don't think it's really a gem.  If anything, it would amount to a duplicate of this question: [Hide Show content-list with only CSS, no javascript used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17731457/691711).  Both questions want conditional rendering without JS, but this one actually started with code, and came almost 6 years earlier.

Comment: Figures I didn't check for dupes.