# What are the methods of detecting vote fraud / sockpuppetry (user cross-voting with multiple accounts)?

Tags: discussion, voting-fraud, sock-puppets

I've seen lots of threads discussing policy about a user with multiple accounts. I know it's fine to have multiple accounts as long as that person doesn't do voting fraud, aka voting for each other.

I'm not asking about what to do when I see voting fraud. How does Stack Overflow detect a user with multiple accounts that vote each other? Is there any specific algorithm and method that they use (general approach would be enough), or is it just based on user reports, flags, etc.?

Comment: I imagine what algorithms exist will not be discussed to prevent people trying to work around them

Comment: I have flagged few of them manually. Its generally obvious, done without much effort. A bad question with a terrible answer tagged wrongly and both upvoted. If you check the users then you see that this happens in various questions. Its easy to catch.

Comment: there are obvious naïve cases, and there are masters in this fraud trade too... I wonder why those people use their energy for that instead of doing constructive things (like actually answering good questions...).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre this is the wrong decade to be talking about people doing constructive things. This is the decade where people do things to not be bored out of their mind.

Comment: The "Related" right column has some interesting past events on how the *community* detects those things.

Comment: I've been flagging some of these for some time too. There are a variety of ways to detect them algorhitmically, and SE's transparency makes it easy to crowdsource the detection partially as well. And we have good mods that'll act on reports when given.

Comment: Why would anyone want a sockpuppet if not to engage in voting fraud, is there a valid use case I'm not thinking of?

Comment: There are a few use-cases for alternate accounts. I can think of three: (1) asking "anonymous" questions that you don't want linked with your main account (i.e., hiding the fact that you're learning PHP), (2) seeing what the plebs^H^H^H^H^H regular users see with less rep/privileges, and (3) for a bot. Now, you could argue these aren't actually *sockpuppets*, precisely because they're not being used to engage in fraudulent activity. The name "sockpuppet" has a negative connotation, but can just be used to mean "a second account". I've never needed it. One is almost more than I can handle. @lan

Answer (score 58, accepted):

We have both automated systems in place that **detect** vote fraud based on certain heuristics, and moderators **investigate** specific instances that are brought to our attention by user flags. Also, once you've been a moderator long enough, you just start to be able to *smell* sockpuppetry (dirty socks—you know the smell), and then you go looking for it.

As far as what **constitutes** sockpuppetry, the definitive explanation can be found [here on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57685/153008) (the global Meta site for the entire Stack Exchange network). It can be summed up as:

> …if the second account allows you to do something on the site that your normal account would be prevented from doing, it is abuse.

Or, an even simpler rule to follow is, if your second account is *interacting* in any way with your first account, then it's a sockpuppet and breaking the rules.

How we actually ***prove*** that an account is a sockpuppet, well, that's a trade secret. We intentionally do not reveal details of these investigations or even the overall process, lest it give users ammunition to evade detection.

But, I can tell you how we **handle** it. As that answer I linked above indicates, when a sockpuppet account is found, it is *deleted*, removing it from the system. This removes all traces of its votes. A moderator also *warns* the operator of the sockpuppet via a private message, which may be accompanied by [a suspension](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) at the discretion of the moderator. A second offense *always* comes with a suspension. The duration of the suspension increases with repeated offenses.

Taking voting fraud seriously is in everyone's interest. It means you can trust the scores of posts on the site, and it means that other people aren't getting an unfair advantage.

Comment: Oo ok that's scary. Revealing the secret might not a good idea, but I can get the main idea how you approach the problem. Thanks for sharing

Comment: Just an interesting thought: "Or, an even simpler rule to follow is, if your second account is interacting in any way with your first account, then it's a sockpuppet and breaking the rules." vs "…if the second account allows you to do something on the site that your normal account would be prevented from doing, it is abuse." what about an answer to a question? that would fit in the first definition, not the second, but _probably_  should be counted as sockpuppetry.

Comment: But some use the bounty system to transfer reputation points to avoid deletion of votes. Is there a way to handle that?

Comment: @PeterMortensen that's basically a zero sum game and very visible though. If it's actually sockpuppetry, doing it via bounty will be incredibly obvious. And CMs can invalidate bounties, mods can cancel them etc....

Comment: @Oranges Yeah, you can technically answer your own question using a sockpuppet account. But you *can't* accept that answer, or vote it up, using the main account (the one that asked the question). So that's one of the edge cases where the "no interaction" rule doesn't *quite* apply, and you need to resort to the more complicated definition. But the "no interaction" rule of thumb is good enough to keep you out of trouble.

Comment: @Peter Yes, awarding yourself a bounty is also fraud. That's a bulk transfer of reputation points on an even larger scale than a couple of upvotes. However, as Magisch pointed out, this is highly visible abuse. All bounties that an account has ever given/received are displayed in their profile, and that's *public* knowledge to everyone (not just moderators). Moderators can cancel pending bounties, but for sockpuppetry, we're going to just delete the sock, which renders any reputation gain irrelevant.

Comment: @oranges Technically you could ask and answer a question with any account so long as the account is not banned from asking or answering questions. As such, asking a question with one account and answering it with another would not allow you to do anything that you would not have otherwise been able to do (again, unless one of these accounts had been banned from performing that action, or rate limited in some way such that the account was not capable of performing that action). So, your example doesn't run afoul of the wording provided in the answer here, not would it be a bad thing.

Comment: "when a sockpuppet account is found, it is *deleted*" - you misspelled *destroyed* ;-)

Comment: @Mathieu Actually, no. Deleting and destroying an account are two different actions. Spammers are destroyed; sockpuppets are deleted. The difference is largely an implementation detail. Grace Note documents the public-facing differences [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/88996/153008), namely that "destroyed" accounts have *all* of their posts deleted, while "deleted" accounts only have their negatively-scored posts deleted (with a few exceptions). Sockpuppets are breaking the rules, but might have contributed useful content, so destruction is contra-indicated.

Comment: Gah, seems I haven't been a mod for too long!

Comment: Are you sure this reputation points laundering scheme doesn't work? Sockpuppet account A upvotes posts of sockpuppet account B. Sockpuppet account B awards bounties to sockpuppet account C. Sockpuppet account A is destroyed. Will sockpuppet account C (not detected as a sockpuppet account) keeps its reputation points?

Comment: Even if it doesn't work that way, perhaps it is a way to avoid detection?

Comment: I don't know about the burden of proof with the available information, but at least as a start, staff should be able to write a simple script to detect it. [Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2963652/nicael?tab=reputation&sort=post&page=27). [Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2963652/nicael?tab=reputation&sort=post&page=28). In the last example, 3 x 500 reputation points within less than 6 seconds.

Comment: Some accounts with a lot of bounty activity have *regular* daily (also often at about the same time of day, within a few hours) upvoting on years-old posts with few views and zero/few existing votes (equal distribution instead of the expected power law).

Comment: I think the way you "prove" someone is a sockpuppet is if they post/interact with the site over the same network. I got banned on meta probably because some trolls happened to use the same network as the shared network I use, and they thought I was their sockpuppet.